# watch state change over time in atmel studio?

Tags: arduino, atmel, atmelstudio

Currently I test my code by debugging in simulator mode and breaking, messing with I/O, and beginning debugger again.

What if I have state that changes on a period though? Is there a way I can just let it 'run' and observe its state change?

Answer (score 0):

I belive the LiveWatch functionality should satisfy your needs.
http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/livewatch/pr01.html

More on how to use it here:
http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/livewatch/livewatch.example.run.html